# ThunderBird 112: Catch-all identity does not work with forwarding

Tags: email, thunderbird

I have set a catch-all identity in the ThunderBird email client. It correctly deduces the "From:" address to use when replying to messages but not when forwarding the message.

Does anyone know how to fix it?